# Margin at top of page is not correct?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have bar at the top of my page but when I first load the page the bar covers the header.  When I click the hide bar arrow on the right hand side, the header shows, and then when I click the reappear arrow the margin automatically resizes so that the header is underneath the bar.

I cant seem to work out why the bar doesnt automatically create a margin when the page is loaded?  Any idea... this is the javascript and the code I am using. The website is also http://www.brightonorient.com

Any help would be really appreciated!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var stub_showing = false;

    function woahbar_show() { 
        if(stub_showing) {
          $('.woahbar-stub').slideUp('fast', function() {
            $('.woahbar').show('bounce', { times:3, distance:15 }, 100); 
            $('body').animate({"marginTop": "2.4em"}, 250);
          }); 
        }
        else {
          $('.woahbar').show('bounce', { times:3, distance:15 }, 100); 
          $('body').animate({"marginTop": "2.4em"}, 250);
        }
    }

    function woahbar_hide() { 
        $('.woahbar').slideUp('fast', function() {
          $('.woahbar-stub').show('bounce', { times:3, distance:15 }, 100);  
          stub_showing = true;
        }); 

        if( $(window).width() > 1024 ) {
          $('body').animate({"marginTop": "0px"}, 250); // if width greater than 1024 pull up the body
        }
    }

    $().ready(function() {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
        woahbar_show();
     }, 5000);
    });
</script>



<div class="woahbar">
   <span>
       Brighton Orient treats you to up to 25% off in honour of Mother's day! Ends midnight this Sunday, 18 March!! <a class="woahbar-link" href="http://www.brightonorient.com/events.html">Click here for details</a>
    </span>
    <a class="close-notify" onclick="woahbar_hide();"><img class="woahbar-up-arrow" src="woahbar-up-arrow.png"></a>
</div>
<div class="woahbar-stub" style="display:none">
    <a class="show-notify" onclick="woahbar_show();"><img class="woahbar-down-arrow" src="woahbar-down-arrow.png"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `style="margin-top: 2.4em;"`is added to the body element after the first repop of the bar. Try adding it to the body css:

```
body { margin-top: 2.4em; }
```

However, that does not explain why the first `animate` does not fire. Maybe try `$(window).load`instead of `$(document).ready`?

Comment: Thank you, that was correct, unfortunately the jquery is clashing with my cufon font rendering so at moment it is just fixed without animation until I find out what the clash is..

Comment: Don't use cufon. Just another bloaty thing to break.